# How to get opacity value as an int for alpha filter?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, opacity

For Internet Explorer opacity is set in inline css like this:

```
style="filter: alpha(opacity=50);"
```

What I'd like to do is get the opacity value as in integer in javascript. Ok I guess I can get the whole string and parse out the int, but is there a faster/better way?

Thanks

Comment: Given that you should probably be using the `opacity` css option for other browsers, just get the value from that and multiply by 100. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript is pretty simple:

```
var opacity = this.filters.alpha.opacity;
```

or if you have an id...

```
var opacity = getElementById('myelement').filters.alpha.opacity;
```